# Generate 200 unique 40-char strings using 3 chars

Tags: c, string, char, unique

I'd like to generate at least 200 unique 40-character strings using only 'a', 'b', or 'c'. For example, a good string would be "aaaa...aaaa" (40-char). Here's my approach so far:

`char newid[41];
sprintf(newid, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa%\n", "bbbb");`

another approach:

```
char newid[41];
char* pad[41] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa;
sprintf(newid, "%s%s\n", pad+4, "bbbb");
```

but I still don't know how to make a loop that would automate the process... (sorry I'm a noob in C). Please help; any hints or approaches are appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `char pad[40];` has enough space for a string 39 characters long.

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot about the null character. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2^64 > 3^40 so just pick 200 *(different)* random 64-bit numbers below `12157665459056928801` and convert to base 3 (with `a`, `b`, and `c` "digits" rather than the usual `0`, `1`, and `2`).

Comment: Is the chance of duplicates large enough to warrant a check on uniqueness?

Comment: Why make them random? Just start at 0 and count to 199.

Comment: @Jongware: lol you're right! Changed "different" to italics and inside parenthesis

Comment: hm, I understand that numbers are stored as binary in C, but how do I go from converting a number from 0-199 to to 'a', 'b', and 'c'? I can convert from binary to base 3, but I'm not sure how to go from base 3 to char "digits"? sorry if that's confusing...

Comment: If you can generate a base-3 string, then simply change `0` to `a`, `1` to `b`, `2` to `c` (actually the exact order isn't even important...). @pmg did not mention that the result base-3 string may be less than 200 characters -- leading zeros are automatically dropped -- so make sure to pad your string.

Comment: Okay, based on both of your inputs, my plan is to have a counter from 0 to 199. And for each count, I would convert that number to a base-3 string (similar to converting an int to a binary string), then change 0, 1, 2 to a, b, c.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo-random number generator to pick randomly between 'a', 'b' and 'c'. To enforce uniqueness, keep track of previously generated `newid` values and discard duplicates

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void generate() {
    char previous[199][40+1];
    char newid[40+1];
    int i, j, unique;
    srand(time(NULL));
    newid[40] = '\0';
    for(i=0; i < 200; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < 40; j++) {
            newid[j] = 'a' + (rand() % 3);
            }
        /* confirm newid is 'unique' */
        unique=1;   
        for(j=0; unique && j < i; j++) {
            if (strcmp(previous[j], newid) == 0)
                unique=0;
            }
        if (!unique) {
            /* discard duplicate */
            i--;
            continue;
            }
        /* save newly genererated unique value */
        strcpy(previous[i], newid);
        printf("%s\n", newid);
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 thank you for this solution! it's quite cool to see another implementation. Unfortunately, I won't be able to use rand() in this file. If you don't mind me asking, what happens when you do (rand() % 3)? I didn't know we could mod chars.

Comment: `(rand() % 3)` will return a random number between 0 and 2 which you add the ascii value of 'a' resulting in a random character between 'a', 'b' and 'c'. Why can't you use rand() ?

Comment: To ensure proper working in awkward character sets, use `"abc"[rand() % 3]`

Comment: Oh, that's smart! But what happens if the char is not conveniently 'a', 'b' or 'c' (e.g. 'a' and 'x')? The file I'm working on doesn't have the std lib, and I can't modify that part. :(

Comment: I've never encountered a platform that did not provide a PRNG (pseudo-random number generation) facility. What ever platform you are programming for, check the api/sdk for the appropriate substitution. Second, if you'd like to change the domain of valid characters, put them in an array, and let your random number be a subscript into this array.